# Enable SSDP Discovery on windows-10-iot with default rules

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windows-firewall

I try to run a aspnetcore application on RaspBerryPi with windows 10 iot.
Fiddling with the firewall I found out, that it is blocking.

```
Rule Name:                            Network Discovery (SSDP-In)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:                             Network Discovery
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             LocalSubnet
Protocol:                             UDP
LocalPort:                            1900
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
```

Anyhow - the firewall blocks the UDP packages.
So I added my own rule:

```
Rule Name:                            MySSDP
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:                             
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             LocalSubnet
Protocol:                             UDP
LocalPort:                            1900
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
```

Now discovery works - but I'm curious why I had to define my own rule.
It looks exactly like the predefined one - except that it has no grouping.

Am I missing something - or is (although it states enable) the SSDP-In rule not active?
If so - how can I check / change the status.

Comment: I have tried in my RaspBerryPi with windows 10 iot running asp.net core app. I have checked the rule of Network Discovery (SSDP-In) and Network Discovery (SSDP-Out), it works okay with not add MySSDP rule.Could you tell me your .net core version and windows iot core version. I tested in .net core 2.0 and windows iot core 15063.

Comment: Hi Michael, versions are the same - when I use "netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off" it also works. Logging droppedconnections shows 1900 RECEIVE. I run my asp.net standard app from the powershell command line - I also had to add rules for port 80 (in/out), but that is something I expected. Is it possible that (SSDP-xx) is somehow not active although it shows "Enabled"?

Comment: Hi ManiAT, I think your problem maybe due to other settings.Please try to reset your RaspBerryPi with windows 10 iot, and then check the problem.Feel free to let me know if it is still the same.